# Why is the acceptance rate at 100%?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, accepted-answer

I clearly have not accepted an answer to [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/36734/saving-route-while-still-connected-to-wifi/36737#36737) but it still shows my acceptance rate to be 100%.[image: webpage]

Comment: [Accept rate is no longer displayed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136951/lets-stop-displaying-a-users-accept-rate/164654#164654).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the points explained in [How does accept rate work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16729/150283) appears to apply here:

> - The accept rate is calculated on questions that are older than 3 days.

The question in question is not old enough to be counted toward your accept rate yet - it's less than an hour old.

In addition, even if the question *was* 3 days old, that answer is relatively new. Another relevant point from the above linked answer:

> - The accept rate is heavily cached and can take 24hrs or more to update.

So this looks like it's [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).